# Haskell-language-server starting in wrong folder in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, haskell, haskell-stack, haskell-language-server

I have a project that looks like this:

```
- my-project
  - backend
    - stack.yaml
    - src
      - ... a bunch of haskell files
    - ... exe & test folders here too
  - frontend
    - ... an Elm frontend app
  - flake.nix
  - ... other files
```

When I open this in vscode (`cd my-project && codium .`) and go to one of the haskell files I get some errors it cannot find packages.

However, when I first cd into the backend folder and then open code (`cd my-project/backend && codium .`) then everything works perfectly.

So I think the HLS is just being started at the root and then not able to pick up the haskell project properly.

I tried adding `"haskell.serverExtraArgs": "--cwd /home/theoddler/Dev/my-project/backend"` to my `.vscode/.settings.json` file, but I get the same errors.

How do I fix this? Can I change the directory where the vscode plugin starts the HLS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into a similar problem, but I am using Cabal instead of Stack. I wasn't quite happy with the solution of moving the files to the root directory just to make a VS Code Plugin work, as this would break my code structure.

I found the following workaround, where my `.cabal` (and hopefully your `stack.yaml`) file can stay in the `./backend/` directory:

1. Add `my-project.code-workspace` to your projects root directory:

```json
{
    "folders": [
        {
            "name": "my-workspace",
            "path": "."
        },
        {
            "name": "backend",
            "path": "backend"
        }
    ],
}
```

2. Use `File -> Open Workspace from File...` and select `my-project.code-workspace`
3. Optionally, add a `./backend/settings.json` to hide the redundant `./backend/` directory from the Explorer sidebar. 
   *Note: whenever you edit a file in `./backend/`, the Explorer will highlight this file inside `backend` folder instead of the `my-workspace/backend` folder - but at least it will disappear again, once you switch to another file.*

Comment: Oh nice! I'll try this out next time I work on that project :D Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

## Workaround

I moved the `stack.yaml`,`stack.yaml.lock` files to the root,
and changed `packages` in the `stack.yaml` file from

```yaml
packages:
  - .
```

to

```yaml
packages:
  - backend
```

That way the HLS is happy and can find my Haskell project properly.

## Other thoughts

I looked into [the code of the vscode-haskell extension](https://github.com/haskell/vscode-haskell/blob/10e048dee65ca4d45a885a6814b2a93c22840b96/src/extension.ts#L108-L110), and it looks like it doesn't support anything other than the root as the directory for HLS for workspaces.

I'm looking into contributing to the vscode haskell extension, adding the functionality to change the working dir for the HLS, but currently my setup for debugging the changes of extensions isn't working, so I'll look into that again later.

For now the workaround is the best I found :(